# Wait for ongoing http request to finish before sending the "same" on again in RXJS / angular

Tags: angular, rxjs

The following scenario. (reduced and abstracted for the community).

I have an angular 16 app with a form.
The form contains many input fields - like "firstName", "surName", "phoneNumber" and so on.

**example code:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="state.surname" (change)="changedInput();" type="text" class="form-control" id="id1">

<input [(ngModel)]="state.firstName" (change)="changedInput();" type="text" class="form-control" id="id1">
```

The function `changedInput` will "log" these changes.

```
changedInput() {
    const body = {...};
    this.http.put('v1/...', body).subscribe(o => {
    }, error => {
      ...
    });
  }
```

What I want to achieve is, that **only one http.put is running at the time** from the frontend application and the upcoming request should wait for the other to finish.

Is this feasable?

(Note: it is not about multi-user-scenario where multiple browser instances are involved)

Answer (score 1):

Just as a suggestion: Using ReactiveFormsModule would make this much easier.

```ts
function requestDummy(value: any) {
  console.log('HTTP request', value);
  return of('HTTP response').pipe(
    delay(2000)
  );
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
    <form [formGroup]="form">
      <input formControlName="surname" type="text" />
      <input formControlName="firstname" type="text" />
    </form>
  `,
})
export class App {
  form = new FormGroup({
    surname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2)]),
    firstname: new FormControl()
  });
  constructor() {
    this.form.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        filter(() => this.form.valid),
        debounceTime(500),
        switchMap(requestDummy),
        takeUntilDestroyed()
      ).subscribe((response) => console.log(response));
  }
}
```

In this scenario, with `valueChanges` you already have a stream of form updates, and using `switchMap` cancels any previous requests if a new update occurs before the response is received.

In case you don't want to cancel previous request, you can use `concatMap` instead of `switchMap`.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that also. I dont have the experience with reactive forms right now. Will it support validation? For example, "surname" needs to be at least 2 characters. Observable? form.valueChanges should not fire if validation fails...

Comment: Sure, you just pass an array of validators as second parameter to the FormControl. In the observable you can just filter out any updates where the forms valid property is false. Code example is updated.

Answer (score 0):

> In your approach, http requests will be queued multiple times, and wait for the previous to complete, Ideally, the latest request will have all the data, so there is only need to make one put call, so we can reduce the number of calls using this method

You can use `subject` along with `debounceTime` to reduce the number of requests!
Please find below a working example!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { of, Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { debounceTime, delay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [FormsModule],
  template: `
    <input [(ngModel)]="name" (change)="changedInput();" type="text" class="form-control" id="id1">

<input [(ngModel)]="name2" (change)="changedInput();" type="text" class="form-control" id="id1">

  `,
})
export class App {
  subscription: Subscription = new Subscription();
  requestSubscription: Subscription | null = null;
  name = 'Angular';
  name2 = 'Angular';
  private changeSubject: Subject<void> = new Subject<void>();

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.changeSubject
        .pipe(
          debounceTime(500) // give any value you want
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
          // cancel the previous request since the latest request contains the proper data
          if (this.requestSubscription) {
            console.log('unsubscribe previous!');
            this.requestSubscription.unsubscribe();
          }
          console.log('time to save!');
          // simulating http request
          this.requestSubscription = of({
            name: this.name,
            name2: this.name2,
          })
            .pipe(delay(2000))
            .subscribe({
              next: () => {
                console.log('next');
              },
              error: () => {
                console.log('error');
              },
              complete: () => {
                console.log('complete');
              },
            });
        })
    );
  }

  changedInput(): void {
    this.changeSubject.next();
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
    if (this.requestSubscription) {
      this.requestSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jqyirx)